T distribution for testing significance of Spearmann correlation coefficient
I look for a proof that one can use statistic $t=r_s \sqrt\frac{n-2}{1-r_s^2}$ which follows t-distribution with n-2 d.f. for testing whether Spearmann correlation coefficient is non equal zero. I know it holds for the Pearson correlation coefficient with assumption of bivariate normal underlaying variables, but I can't find justification why it is good approximation in case of Spearman coefficient as well. Wikipedia article gives only reference to a paper with numerical justification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance.
I would really appreciate an explanation or book references.
